# Access Database, Connection string jiggery pokerery

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection-string

I am trying, from my c# codefile to access an Access Database.  If I use the:

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)

with the connection string being:

> connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\testing_dev\sm_development\App_Data\SMWeb.mdb"

I get an error when I try and create a dataset that the word 'provider' is not supported!  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
string connectionString= @"Data Source=F:\testing_dev\sm_development\App_Data\SMWeb.mdb";
```

OleDbConnection is in the System.Data.OleDb namespace.

Answer (score 4):

The "Sql" in "SqlConnection", "SqlCommand", and generally anything in System.Data.SqlClient refers strictly to Sql Server.  MS Access is definitely not Sql Server.  Look in the System.Data.OleDb namespace instead.

Answer (score 1):

Put down the SqlConnection and pick up the [OleDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx):

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;

public class DataAccess
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KeyName"].ConnectionString;

    public DataSet GetData( string sql, string tableName )
    {
        using( var conn = new OleDbConnection( connectionString ) )
        {
            conn.Open();
            var da = new OleDbDataAdapter( sql, conn );
            var ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill( ds, tableName );
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this for access 2007

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/My_DB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;
```

Answer (score -1):

if u r trying this in c# please try to write "\" two time in the path 
for example

"F:\testing_dev\sm_development\App_Data\SMWeb.mdb";

otherwise all okey

Comment: Where are the two back slashes in your example??